# SQL: Calculate number of days since last success

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Following table represents results of given test.

Every result for the same test is either pass ( error_id=0) or fail ( error_id <> 0)
I need help to write a query, that returns the number of runs since last good run ( error_id= 0) and the date.

```
| Date       | test_id | error_id |
-----------------------------------
| 2019-12-20 | 123     | 23
| 2019-12-19 | 123     | 23
| 2019-12-17 | 123     | 22
| 2019-12-18 | 123     | 0
| 2019-12-16 | 123     | 11
| 2019-12-15 | 123     | 11
| 2019-12-13 | 123     | 11
| 2019-12-12 | 123     | 0
```

So the result for this example should be:

```
| 2019-12-18 | 123  | 4
```

as the test 123 was PASS on 2019-12-18 and this happened 4 runs ago.

I have a query to determine whether given run is error or not, but I have trouble applying appropriate window function to it to get the wanted result

```
select test_id, Date, error_id,  (CASE WHEN error_id  0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as is_error
from testresults
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a row number, in reverse order from the sorting of the query itself:

```
SELECT test_date, test_id, error_code, 
       (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY test_date asc) - 1) as runs_since_last_pass
FROM tests
WHERE test_date >= (SELECT MAX(test_date) FROM tests WHERE error_code=0)
ORDER BY test_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that this will run into issues if `test_date` is not unique.  Better use a timestamp (precise to the millisecond) instead of a date.

Here's a DBFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8gSHVcXMztuRiFcL8zLeEx/0

If there's more than one test_id, you'll want to add a PARTITION BY clause to the row number function, and the subquery would become a bit more complex.  It may be more efficient to come up with a way to do this by a JOIN instead of a subquery, but it would be more cognitively complex.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Maximum date of the good runs for every test_id in your query. You can try this query:

```
select tr2.Date_error, tr.test_id,  count(tr.error_id)  from 
testresults tr inner join (select max(Date_error), test_id 
from testresult where error_id=0 group by test_id) tr2 on 
tr.test_id=tr2.test_id and tr.date_error >=tr2.date_error 
group by test_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want aggregation and some filtering:

```
select id, count(*),
       max(date) over (filter where error_id = 0) as last_success_date
from t
where date > (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.error_id = 0);
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
select count(*) from table t,
(select max(date) date from table where error_id = 0) good
where t.date >= good.date
```

Basically you are counting the rows that have a date >= the date of the last success.

**Please note**: If you need the number of days, it is a complete different query:

```
select now()::date - max(test_date) last_valid from tests
where error_code = 0;
```